# How to get custom reusable workflow feature in CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, designer-workflow, csom

I have created a custom reusable workflow in SharePoint Designer. I am facing an issue after deployment of workflow. I have to activate the workflow feature with CSOM but I am not able to get that feature with CSOM code. I have tried code but this code is not showing that custom workflow feature id. I have tried on web & site level also :

```
public static void GetAllWebFeatures(ClientContext ctx, Web web)
{

try
{
var webFeatures = web.Features;
ctx.Load(webFeatures, fcol => fcol.Include(f => f.DisplayName, f => f.DefinitionId));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var f in webFeatures)
{
Console.WriteLine(f.DisplayName);
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
Helper.WriteException("Error in GetAllFeatures", ex);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusable workflows are not created for specific list or library but as the name suggests, they can be associated to any list or library. If you create a reusable workflow from SharePoint designer, you need Associate the workflow to a List to make it works.

The following article for your reference.

[SharePoint 2013: Create Reusable Workflow on Content Type using SharePoint Designer 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33157.sharepoint-2013-create-reusable-workflow-on-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx)

If you want to get the workflow from the list, for SharePoint 2010 workflow, we can use the code below.

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");
clientContext.Load(list);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var workflows = list.WorkflowAssociations;
clientContext.Load(workflows);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
for (int i = 0; i < workflows.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(workflows[i].Name);
    Console.WriteLine(workflows[i].Id);
}
```

For SharePoint 2013 workflow, we can use this.

```
WorkflowServicesManager workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(clientContext,web);
clientContext.Load(workflowServiceManager);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
clientContext.Load(workflowSubscriptionService);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Guid listId = new Guid("{9AA28BEC-8195-4355-B933-C4BFC753647E}");
var subscriptions = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(listId);
clientContext.Load(subscriptions);
foreach (var sub in subscriptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sub.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(sub.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want to activate the feature of custom workflow. I am not able to find custom workflow feature id.

Comment: The reusable workflow like a workflow template, it is not run as a feature, you need associate the reusable workflow to a list to make it works.